# Не удается обратиться к нужному селектору и вызвать функцию jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть связаныне списки, которые я хочу перенести в итоговый проект на сайт на движке **wordpress**. На тестовом работает хорошо, а вот в рабочем запись с *:nth-child(2)* - `li.sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat:nth-child(2) select` не воспринимает. Если еще для parent обхожусь так

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat")[0].getElementsByClassName("sf-input-select")[0]
```

то как быть с `$children = $('li:nth-child(2) select');` ?

**Код**

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    var parent = 'li:nth-child(1) select',
      $children = $('li:nth-child(2) select');

    $(document).on('change', parent, function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val(),
        start = $children.find('option[value="' + value + '"]').index(),
        $childrens = $children.find('option').slice(start + 1);

      $children.find('option').hide();

      $childrens.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.sf-level-0')) {
          return false;
        }

        $(this).show();
      });
    });

    $(parent).trigger('change');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat" data-sf-field-name="_sft_ad_cat" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select" data-sf-combobox="1" data-sf-term-rewrite="[&quot;http:\/\/site.com\/ad-category\/[0]\/&quot;]">
    <label>
  <select data-combobox="1" name="_sft_ad_cat[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">марка а/м</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="12" data-sf-depth="0" value="audi">Audi</option>  
  </select>
</label>
  </li>

  <li class="sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat" data-sf-field-name="_sft_ad_cat" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select" data-sf-combobox="1" data-sf-term-rewrite="[&quot;http:\/\/site.com\/ad-category\/[0]\/&quot;]">
    <label>
  <select data-combobox="1" name="_sft_ad_cat[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">марка а/м</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-59" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="156">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;156</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19" data-sf-count="10" data-sf-depth="0" value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-60" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6c5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A6C5</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-61" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A4</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-62" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A6</option>
  </select>
</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "В тестовом работает" - сверьте версии jQuery. В общем, нужно искать разницу в окружении.

Comment: @vp_arth вот такой подход срабатывает `var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat")[0].getElementsByClassName("sf-input-select")[0]` задача переписать детей что-то наподобие такого, но это вызывает ошибку ($ = функция)  `$children = $('document.getElementsByClassName("sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat")[0].getElementsByClassName("sf-input-select")[0]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть решение. Вместо `:nth-child` поставил `select:first` и `select:last` и заработало! Кто подскажет почему - получит плюсик в карму

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    var parent = 'li select:first',
      $children = $('li select:last');

    $(document).on('change', parent, function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.val(),
        start = $children.find('option[value="' + value + '"]').index(),
        $childrens = $children.find('option').slice(start + 1);

      $children.find('option').hide();

      $childrens.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('.sf-level-0')) {
          return false;
        }

        $(this).show();
      });
    });

    $(parent).trigger('change');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat" data-sf-field-name="_sft_ad_cat" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select" data-sf-combobox="1" data-sf-term-rewrite="[&quot;http:\/\/site.com\/ad-category\/[0]\/&quot;]">
    <label>
  <select data-combobox="1" name="_sft_ad_cat[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">марка а/м</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="12" data-sf-depth="0" value="audi">Audi</option>  
  </select>
</label>
  </li>

  <li class="sf-field-taxonomy-ad_cat" data-sf-field-name="_sft_ad_cat" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select" data-sf-combobox="1" data-sf-term-rewrite="[&quot;http:\/\/site.com\/ad-category\/[0]\/&quot;]">
    <label>
  <select data-combobox="1" name="_sft_ad_cat[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">марка а/м</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-59" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="156">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;156</option>
    <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-19" data-sf-count="10" data-sf-depth="0" value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-60" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6c5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A6C5</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-61" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A4</option>
    <option class="sf-level-1 sf-item-62" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="1" value="a6">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A6</option>
  </select>
</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```